# LTspice not recognizing model embedded in schematic

Tags: ltspice

I am trying to use some third party models in a simulation and getting an error saying "model not found" no matter how I try to reference them (.lib, .inc or pasting model file directly into the sheet).  In this case I have pasted the model text directly into the sheet.  Am I missing a setting?

[image: Schematic Sheet]

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use a `.subckt`, not a `.model`, therefore if you're using the symbol for the diode you have to change its prefix to `X`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R-Click</kbd> on the diode's symbol, double click on the `Prefix` entry, change `D` to `X` (case insensitive). BTW, your `.subckt` definition is missing an `.ends` -- it might not matter here, but if you plan on adding other subcircuits, there may be clashes. It never hurts adding one `.ends`.

Comment: Thanks the ctrl+ right click part was what I was missing.